# Ideal in a $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a non-unital $C^*$ algebra, $a\in A$, $I$ is the ideal generated by $a$.

In the unital case, $a=1a1\in AaA$. But in the non-unital case, how to show that $a\in A$, can $a$ be expressed by elements in $AaA$?

Comment: I don't know much about C-star algebras, but often the definition of the ideal generated by some set (or element) is the smallest ideal that contains the  set (or the element). In this case it would be true by definition. You may want to include the definition of what you ask about.

Comment: I guess you want to know if $a\in AaA$? Because the definition of the ideal generated by $a$ is as @quid stated. Equivalently: you want to know if the ideal generated by $a$ is $AaA$, even for non-unital $C^*$-algebras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume we are talking (as usual) about closed bilateral ideals. Any C$^*$-algebra has an approximate unit $\{e_j\}$: that is, $0\leq e_j$, $\|e_j\|\leq 1$, and $\lim_j e_ja=\lim_jae_j=a$ for all $a\in A$. Then 
$$
a=\lim_j e_jae_j\in \overline{AaA},
$$
without even needing sums.

Comment: Note that you can take $a=\lim e_ja$ without the second $e_j$. Furthermore, this only shows $a\in\overline{AaA}$. However it is quite rare that we talk about non-closed ideals, so this is not very important. Finally, I don't think $e_j\leq I$ makes sense. I think it should be $\|e_j\|\leq1$.

Comment: Are there any examples to show that the ideal $I$ genrated by an element in $A$ is equal to $A$?

Comment: @SmileyCraft: why would $e_ja\in AaA$? Point taken about the closure. As for $e_j\leq I$, I have never seen anybody use non-positive approximate units; and when $e_j\geq0$, the conditions $\|e_j\|\leq1$ and $e_j\leq I$ are the same.

Comment: @mathrookie: yes, take any nonzero element in any simple C$^*$-algebra.

Comment: @MartinArgerami The $e_ja\in AaA$ was indeed a mistake on my part. However, I still don't understand what $e_j\leq I$ is supposed to mean. What is $I$? There is no unit.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean. It's so common to work on the unitization in this context, that I forgot about it.

Comment: @Martin Argerami,If $A$ is a non-unital nuclear $C^*$ algeabra,but it is not simple,$a\in A$ ,Let I be the ideal generated by a,do there still exist those examples that $I=A$?

Comment: Yes, of course. Take $K (H)\oplus K (H) $ and $a=(T,S) $ where $T,S $ are any nonzero compact operators. Or $c_0\oplus c_0$ and $a=(x,y) $, with $x,y $ strictly positive. Etc.